# How to determine the last character of a string in which it will be the first character of the next string

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

How can I get the last letter of a string in which it will be the first letter of the next string.

I know this has something to do with `charAt()` but I don't know how to do it with arrays

Let's say we have an **input** like this `x = {"rojan", "yohan", "jamir", "nancy", "nene", "neels"}`

The **output** will be `jamir, rojan, nancy, yohan, nene`

The program will disregard if there were other character/letter that links to the previous character.

Comment: Can you give a more focused problem statement than this?  What would happen if you had three words which could not be linked in a last character to first character relationship?  What would the output be then?

Comment: it will stop if the program couldn't find anything that starts with that letter.

Comment: OK...but what is the logic should there be multiple possible matches?  Do you see how this can get out of hand very quickly?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this? It might help us to answer your question.

Comment: @RubyRaeOlaya Maybe you should write what is a real question must be answered - "How can I get the last letter of a string in which it will be the first letter of the next string" or "how can I get such output based on such input"? Because answering the first question does not give an answer to the second one

Comment: @byxor well I am curious what will I code if I encounter this in a programming contest

Answer (score 0):

You can use an arraylist to get your final data but you must check for the first char before checking the last char for every word so you don't miss any data.If you only check the last it will be **rojan** > **nancy**> **yohan** > **nene** .So **jamir** is out of the sequence because I didn't look for **r** which is unrealistic .So do it this way:-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NewClass1 {

public static void  main (String [] args){

String [] x= {"rojan", "yohan", "jamir", "nancy", "nene","neels"};/*your 
array*/

ArrayList<String> newarray = new <String>ArrayList();//resulting array


int j=0;
int i=1;
int check=1;//check 1 means its checking first character

for(;i<x.length-1;i++){//loop will stop at nene

while(newarray.contains(x[i])){//prevent reusing the same word
   i++;

}while(newarray.contains(x[j])){//prevent reusing the same word
j++;
}

if(check==1){

if(x[i].charAt(x[i].length()-1)==x[j].charAt(0)){//checking first character

newarray.add(x[i]);
newarray.add(x[j]);

 check=2;//setting to 2 after first character found

i=-1;//resetting loop after looking for char
}


}else
if(x[i].charAt(0)==x[j].charAt(x[j].length()-1)){//checking last character

newarray.add(x[i]);
j++;
check=1;//resetting to 1 after last character found
i=-1;
}

}
for(i =0 ;i<newarray.size();i++){//for printing the array
System.out.print(" "+newarray.get(i));
}
}
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've tested this solution as I've understood incorrectly at first